# Proper way to access data on list with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm developing a VOIP server on UDP using Netty. When a call is placed, I store a "call" object on a global list of calls, like this:

```
public final List<Call> calls = new ArrayList<Call>();
```

Every time i receive a response from a Call, i have to iterate through the list to find the right "call" then, use this call object to make decisions, maybe route the call to another place, etc.

My currently lazy solution to this threading problem is to use the **synchronized** key word over the whole list, every time I need to access the list OR the individual "call" objects. I know this is terrible but it's OK for a POC.

Now I need the do the right way. To the access the list, using a **ConcurrentHashMap** seems to be a good option, but my question is:
What is the proper way to lock and access individual **"call"** objects ?

I can have up to 4k simultaneous calls (500 packets/sec), could it be a problem to lock a lot of objects? What is the best solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Proper way to access data on list with multiple threads" i.e. solve my question

Comment: I'm looking for a solution, isn't collaboration the purpose of stackoverflow? I'm not just forwarding a basic question, it's a complex scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* to lock the call objects from the outside?  I am assuming that the call object is essentially 2 FIFO queues - one processing audio packets from caller1 to caller2, the second processing packets from caller2 to caller1.  You can have methods that lock these queues internally (and individually) as they add/remove the "next" packet.  Other than that, it seems like the data in the call object would be rather static through the life of the call.  This also allows concurrent data processing for each direction of the call since any operation on a packet in one direction won't impact the other direction.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by outside. I think "yes" I do. It's not really a queue because there is no specific order to enter or leave the list. In this case, i'm talking about SIP signalling, so all audio packets are handled elsewhere. The logic is: generate a call to A side, wait to be answered, generate call to B side, wait to be answered, then ask audio processor to bridge them. In the meanwhile, both sides can send packets and these have to be forwarded. This is the problem with the locks.

Comment: "Outside" means locking the call object as a whole from non-Call-class code.

"Both sides send packets and these have to be forwarded"  So each side has a queue in the call object to forward to the other side, each with its own lock internal to the call object.

Comment: Re: audio vs. other packets, kind of irrelevant, though I have done this kind of thing passing around audio packets in my own code before.

Comment: So yes, need to lock the call from outside, probably 100% times. Do you think having 200-300 simultaneous locks, can lead to big problems? I think in a way to avoid a deadlock.

Comment: I don't see it, but you know your code better than I.  I might be concerned about the ConcurrentHashMap.  Seems to me I tried using that a few years back and it really didn't do what I needed.  Ended up wrapping a regular HashMap with a read/write lock (write lock for adding/removing entries only).  But I may have had different requirements than you do.  Probably worth testing.

Comment: Locks should not be big objects.  Lock classes I wrote in the past were on the order of a few bytes (12 on the outside?) in C++.  I usually go for more locks at lower levels in the code for better performance.  Fewer locks at higher levels usually block when/where they don't really need to, hindering performance.  Hence my recommendation for the locks inside of the Call class.